# Exchange 2010: How to retain mail in the outgoing queue for a certain amount of time before it is being sent

Tags: exchange-2010

One of our clients asked us to configure Exchange 2010 to retain outgoing mail for a certain amount of time (independant of Outlook settings.) The idea is that an administrator has about 10 minutes to take a message out of a queue before it is sent out 
the organization.

I know this can be configured in Outlook, but this is not a valiable solution for us. I'm also aware that this causes queues to fill up, this is part of the consideration.

Is there a way in Exchange 2010 to configure this?

Comment: Is the administrator spending all of his/her time watching the mail queue, or is something (an alert or trigger) going to pique his interest?  Also you're missing a preposition in the phrase 'it is sent out the organization'.  Do you mean 'out of the organization' or 'out to the organization'?

Comment: The mail queues aren't manually monitored. Problem is that sometimes people press the send button in Outlook and then realize they made a few mistakes. They want to have a way to let an administrator remove a message from queue before it is going out on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this in Exchange 2010. You could write a script to freeze the queues every so often (say, at the top of the hour) then unfreeze them periodically, but that's kind of ugly and doesn't exactly do what you want.

Comment: Indeed this wouldn't work. Because a message has no guaranteed way to remain in a queue for an X number of minutes. If the queue unfreezes right after a message is sent, it is going out more or less right away.